# Proceeding to another activity and/or fragment on TextView click

Tags: java, android

this is some text lyl
this is some text lyl
this is some text lylthis is some text lyl
this is some text lyl
this is some text lyl

```
 public void click(View v){
    Intent intent;
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.nav_Courses:
            fragment = new CoursesActivity();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to open an `Activity` from your `Fragment`.

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_page, container, false);

        final Textview textview = view.findViewById(R.id.date_apr);
        textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemDetailActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }
          });
        return view;
    }
```

To open a Fragment you can use this code in another onclickListener.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container,new CoursesActivity,"");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

*container* is the FrameLayout of your first Fragment.